# IntelliJ IDEA: Corrupted Artifacts of Submodules

Tags: maven, svn, intellij-idea

Scenario:
I had a workspace/project that refered to the trunk (version 0.3.6-SNAPSHOT) of a svn-project.
I switched this workspace to a branch (0.3.5.1-SNAPSHOT) and did 'mvn clean install' via command line and 'reimport project' via maven helper in IDEA.

In Project-Settings > Artifacts is a list of all auto-detected artifacts,
each one .war and one .war exploded.

This list did not update properly, all artifacts kept the same version number  as the project from trunk.
So instead of "server-0.3.5.1-SNAPSHOT.war" I had a "server-0.3.6-SNAPSHOT.war"
Same for all artifacts and exploded versions of these artifacts.

I tried deleting them and doing reimport (via mvn helper plugin), which made it even worse: the exploded versions listed only the 'output root' and had no files listed after all.

I ended up creating a totally new workspace/project which worked fine.

But I am still curious: 
How did I corrupt/destroy my workspace/project?

Comment: Do you switch branches externally or using IDEA? Looks like there are similar requests on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116600, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87850

Comment: I switched using IDEA's Update Project > Update/Switch to a specific url to the branches Head Revision with Depth working copy.